# How to print a specific index value with the help of loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP. Stuck on some point. Need some help. I have a multidimensional array as below. I have an array something like following.

What I want to do is echo as many blocks as the length of main_array. Then print values of every sub_array in each block. Like I want to pick sub_array index0 value from every sub array and print them somewhere in every block. Then index 1 value of every sub array somewhere in every block. Remember things will not run sequentially. Maybe after index0 I go to index3 and print its value somewhere in every block. If  go to more detail lets say I want to pick index4 value of sub_array4 and print it in every block. Can someone please help me?

```
$main_array = array(
'sub_array1' => array(
    'index0' => 'some value',
    'index1' => 'some value',
    'index2' => 'some value',
    'index3' => array(
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
    ),
'sub_array2' => array(
    'index0' => 'some value',
    'index1' => 'some value',
    'index2' => 'some value',
    'index3' => array(
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
    ),
'sub_array3' => array(
    'index0' => 'some value',
    'index1' => 'some value',
    'index2' => 'some value',
    'index3' => array(
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
    ),
'sub_array4' => array(
    'index0' => 'some value',
    'index1' => 'some value',
    'index2' => 'some value',
    'index3' => array(
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
        'some value',
    ),
);
```

Comment: _If go to more detail lets say I want to pick index4 value **of sub_array4** and print it in every block._ This differs from the previous requirements, is it a mistake ?

Comment: I am sorry for making mistake. What I actually want to do is take the index2 of every sub_array and print it in every block. Please help! I want to target the element or print the element with name 'index2'.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Barmar. I got it working with the help of PHP array_column function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($main_array as $key => $sub_array) {
      echo $sub_array["index2"];
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks dear!

Comment: No problem. If you could select my answer as the answer to the question, that'd be great!